# Bug with writing bitset to file

Tags: c++, debugging, binaryfiles

I have this function for a compression assignment (due 2 days ago, I'm just trying to find out what went wrong).

It's supposed to print out to stdout the output or write it to file.
The stdout output is 100% accurate.

However, the binary writing always produces garbage. E.g. it's supposed to be 23 bytes of output, but is always 16 bytes, and isn't anything like what it's supposed to be. I've stared at this for 2 hours, could anyone provide a hint as to what's wrong?

Thank you so much.

```
void writer(char character, int count,std::string outputpath){
    if(outputpath == "cout"){
        switch(count){
            case 1:{
                std::cout << character;
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                std::cout << character<< character;
                break;
            }
            default:{
                std::cout << character;
                auto output = conversion(count);
                for(auto i: *output){
                    std::cout << i;
                }
            }
        }
    }else{

        std::vector<std::bitset<8>> source;
        std::bitset<8>temp(character);
        switch(count){
            case 1:{
                source.push_back(temp);
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                source.push_back(temp);
                source.push_back(temp);
                break;
            }
            default:{
                source.push_back(temp);
                auto output = conversion(count);
                for(auto i: *output){
                    source.push_back(i);
                }
            }
        }

        //write
        {
            std::ofstream file( outputpath, std::ios::binary ) ; // output file stream

            // write the contents of the vector to the file
            for( auto i : source ){
                file.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>( &i ), 8 ) ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the inputs? What are the outputs? Both the correct text and incorrect binary outputs - you can examine the latter with hexdump or similar. What was the _expected_ binary output?

Comment: Where is the `main()` function that would allow us to reproduce the issue without guessing the parameters for `writer()` and having to write the `main()` ourselves? And have you, in your 2 hours of staring, perhaps attempted to narrow down the point of error, e.g. by adding some "checking my assumptions" output? What is `conversion()`? If it matters, why didn't you include its definition? If it doesn't matter, why is it being called in your example? Narrow it down. That's debugging 101.

Comment: I wonder why you have two completely different paths through `writer()` for stdout and file output. You could do exactly identical things to your input, and then decide whether to `write()` to `std::cout` or `file`... Also, `reinterpret_cast`. That's a code smell right there, this kind of cast is almost *never* really necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will include more information in future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>( &i ), 8 ) ;
```

The second parameter to [write()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) is the number of **characters** that will be written. `&i` is the location of a 8 **bit** bitset.

All the other problems with your source aside (for which you should perhaps go to codereview.SE), that should be a `1`, not a `8`.

Also, on every call to `writer()`, you *re-open* the output file, overwriting its contents in the process.

---

You didn't show us the calling code. But with a simple tweak, you could've made the (reportedly fully functional) `std::cout` code work for files as well -- by passing `std::ostream &` instead of a filename to the function, and leave it to the caller whether to invoke `writer()` with `std::cout` or opening `outputpath`:

```
void writer( char character, int count, std::ostream & out )
{
    switch( count )
    {
        case 1:
        {
            out << character;
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            out << character << character;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            out << character;
            auto output = conversion( count );
            for ( auto i: *output )
            {
                out << i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling for `std::cout` output:

```
writer( character, count, std::cout );
```

Calling for file output:

```
std::ofstream file( outputpath, std::ios::binary );
// ...
writer( character, count, file );
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i keep getting confused where its chars or bytes

Comment: @killingtime1: On any machine you're likely to be using at this time, chars == bytes. `sizeof char` is *specified* to be 1,  `CHAR_BIT` is 8 on most modern architectures. You confused chars and **bits** here.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks a lot for the example of how to rewrite it, I didn't even think of doing that.

Comment: @killingtime1: "Any good solution is obvious.... once you've found it." ;-)